# MVC Where condition with search function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, where-clause

I am trying to make search function with actionLink.

the actionLink will give parameter to controller such as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Intel Core i5", "Search", "Store", new { @searchString = "i5" }, null)
```

I pass this value and it is working in controller. However, when I trying to compare decimal datatype, not string datatype. Currently, processor is varchar, and dissplaySize is decimal.

I don't know how to handle displaySize with searchString.

My controller is this.

```
//Controller here
 public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {

        var product = from a in _db.Product.Include(a => a.Category)
                      select a;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            //processor is working because searchString is string, however, 
            //displaySize is not working because of decimal value, and 
            // I don't know how to write Where condition in here.
            product = product.Where(a => a.processor.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                               ||
                   //a.displaySize.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            //I repalce to below code, but it has error 
            //'Entity does not recognize the method ''System.String ToString()' method.
                   Convert.ToDecimal(a.displaySize).ToString().Contains(searchString)

        }
        return View(product.ToList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

definitely `a.displaySize.ToString().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));` wouldnt serve the puprpose. try comparing the integer part of the decimal value with the search string that will  give more accurate results. like this `Convert.ToInt32(a.displaySize).ToString().Contains(searchString)`

Comment: Than you for replying, but I have got error, 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method'. How can I convert decimal to string for comparing with searchString?

Comment: so how were u doing this in the example you provided? was this the error for which u actually posted the question?

Comment: Yes. just I replaced the coding from mine what I posted before. I put same as this 'Convert.ToInt32(a.displaySize).ToString().Contains(searchString)' in Where condition.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx check this link u can convert the values in linq to entities using SqlFunctions.StringConvert Method

Comment: Thank you Parv Sharma. When I put like 'SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a.displaySize).Contains(searchString)', it is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, when I put decimal value such as 21.5 instead of 21, it is not working in this case. When I put 21, it will be shown in the list, but not decimal value. When I use String Convert, it says decimal value. Why it happens? sorry about that.

Comment: what is the decimal value of the display size and search string u are using for the case for which it aint working?