# MVC LINQ with Where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, where-clause

I am trying to make search function in my project.

Currently, I want to convert decimal value to string for comparing with searchString.

When I put like this:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {

        var product = from a in _db.Product.Include(a => a.Category)
                      select a;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            product = product.Where(a => a.model.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                               || Convert.ToInt32(a.displaySize).ToString().Contains(searchString));
        }
        return View(product.ToList());
    }
```

It has error,

> 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method'.

How can I compare decimal value with string value?

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140634/mvc-where-condition-with-search-function

Comment: I resolved this problem through 'SqlFunctions.StringConvert(a.displaySize).Contains(searchString)'.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use C# functions that can't be converted to SQL like `.ToString()`. You can use LINQ to Objects instead if your table isn't very large by calling `.ToList()` before `Where`

```
product = product.ToList().Where(a => a.model.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                                   || Convert.ToInt32(a.displaySize).ToString().Contains(searchString));
```

**EDIT:**

You can use functions from `SqlFunctions` namespace. that functions can easily be converted to SQL.

Comment: On a very large list this would be very slow as the ToList would cause the linq to be executed and then you are doing your where.

Comment: I've already mentioned that the way to call .ToList() is good only for tables with a few number of rows.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see that there. but as you mentioned it i apologize

Comment: string str = Convert.ToInt32(a.displaySize).ToString(); I am confused as to how this would work. You are only checking one object before the linq query

Comment: @RyanBennett, I've missed part really.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting your string value (query parameter) to a decimal and comparing the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are searching for two different things. I would split this linq statment at the ||. If you are looking for whatever a.model is, go to one method, if you are looking for the int value go to another and convert the search string to an int BEFORE the linq statment.  That method would like something like:

```
int searchInt;

 if(int.TryParse(searchString, out searchInt))
{

    product = product.Where(a => a.displaySize == searchInt); 
}
```

You have to do this because SQL doesn't have a ToString() method... so LINQ doesn't really know what to do with it. Remember that this all gets converted to SQL.